# How to set two elements be next each other using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make my css with flexbox, so I followed some articles and tried to set my elements like this example:

**the elements 1 & 2 are in another container**

[image: First is the current]

I'm trying to set the two elements (1 and 3) to be next each other as the second example (The first is what I have now and the other is what I'm trying to achieve.)

but I can't find a good way with the Flexbox since I set the container to `flex-direction: column;`

```
            <div class="container">
            <div class="sub-ctn">
              <h5 class="1"><span>♦ </span>{{ text }}</h5>
                <span class="2">{{ value }}</span>


              <div class="3">
                  <h5>{{ text }}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    direction: rtl;
}

.sub-ctn {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    margin-top: 1%;
    flex-direction: column;
}       


.1 {
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
}

.2 {
    float: right;
    /* text-align: right; */
}

.3 {
    margin-left: 1%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

let me know if another information is needed

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `float` and `flex` together. Flex alone will be much easier and better.

```css
.cont{
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}

.left-cont{
   height: 100%;
   flex-grow: 1;
}

.right-cont{
   flex-grow: 1;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.item{
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
 <div class="left-cont">
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-cont">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```